# Why can hard drive recovery software see files on an external hard drive when my Mac can't connect?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a 7-8 year old Lacie HDD that was working great up until last week when it stopped mounting to my Mac.  I searched on a bunch of forums and read various things and learned basically nothing useful.  I downloaded Diskdrill and it shows all of the files are still on the drive.  What I don't understand is why Diskdrill can see the files (and theoretically recover them, I haven't done that yet) but my computer can't mount the drive?  I talked to a support person at Lacie and asked them and they gave kind of vague explanations like the Diskdrill software goes "deeper" into the hard drive, which obviously doesn't explain anything, like if that's all that's needed, can't the Mac also go "deeper"?

The paranoid side of me feels like this is some industry scam, the Diskdrill software costs $90 to use three times, data recovery services seem expensive, I assume they're just running something like the Diskdrill software on the drive.

I don't actually think it's a scam, but I am interested if there's a real explanation for the difference between what Diskdrill or other recovery software is doing that the Mac Disk Utility can't do.

Also seems hard to google because the results are mostly ads for data recovery services and software.

I'm not asking for help with the drive, just curious what the recovery software is doing that regular computer function can't.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest terms, the Mac looks at the file table as presented to it. If that's gone wrong, it doesn't look any further.
Built-in tools such as the unix-based diskutil will have a go at repairing the tables, but they will not dig as deep as dedicated recovery tools.

Recovery software such as DiskDrill will scavenge for evidence of older versions of the file table & even sector by sector across the drive to try to rebuild file structures including known file-type patterns & data headers, using whatever remaining evidence it can find. Usually by this time, 'useful' directory info such as file & folder names are lost & it will try to recreate files as file0001.txt or file002.jpg.

Product recommendations are frowned upon here, so I can't really recommend DiskWarrior ;)
I don't know if they have a free trial [I doubt it] but it is the singular best tool to **recreate** a broken file table on an HFS+ drive. This, if it worked, would restore the drive to a fully-working state.
It may not work on a drive that is completely unmountable - I've never needed it to dig that deep.
For any such rescue. it's best to try image the drive to another first, then work on the image, but DiskWarrior will report whether or not it can fix the drive & present you with back to back virtual copies of before & after, before you commit any write at all, so it will never make any situation worse.

In the long term, you eventually build yourself a little armoury of all these various tools. Each of them has its 'best-use-case' scenario.

Also, backups are a good idea;)